# 16x16 Texture too big, Java openGL

Tags: java, opengl, 2d, textures, terrain

I'm making a tile based game, and the Textures for the Tiles are 16x16. Whenever I try to load the Texture so it can be rendered, 
I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Attempt to allocate a texture to big for the current hardware
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:292)
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:231)
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:184)
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader.getTexture(TextureLoader.java:64)
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader.getTexture(TextureLoader.java:24)
at main.Tile.loadTexture(Tile.java:124)
at main.Draw.drawMap(Draw.java:282)
at main.Draw.render(Draw.java:324)
at main.LaunchWindow.main(LaunchWindow.java:65)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at main.Draw.drawMap(Draw.java:284)
at main.Draw.render(Draw.java:324)
at main.LaunchWindow.main(LaunchWindow.java:65)
```

Now, I know that my gpu can handle it because its a 1GB card.

I ran

```
GL11.glGetInteger(GL11.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE)
```

and got 16384.

Here is the code for loading the Texture:

```
public void loadTexture(String a){
    try {
        texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(a));
        System.out.println(texture.getTextureRef());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the code called when it needs to be rendered:

```
public void drawMap(Map b){
    Color.white.bind();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    b.divideMap(10);
    Tile[][] t = b.makeMap(b.getK());

    for(int y = 0; y < b.tiles.length; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < b.tiles[y].length; x++){
            Texture a;
            t[y][x].loadTexture(t[y][x].getLocation());
            a = t[y][x].getTexture();
            System.out.println(a.getTextureRef());
            a.bind();
            glTexCoord2f(0,0);
            glVertex2f(x,y);
            glTexCoord2f(1,0);
            glVertex2f(x + a.getWidth(), y);
            glTexCoord2f(1,1);
            glVertex2f(x + a.getWidth(), y +  a.getHeight());
            glTexCoord2f(0,1);
            glVertex2f(x, y +  a.getHeight());
        }
    }

    glEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know the framework, but from the code i see you're loading all textures every frame and never release them. After a few frames you're out of memory.